# LINQ2SQL Alternatives for MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, monodevelop

I couldn't find the IDE to create and modify LINQ2SQL on MonoDevelop. I am on OSX right now. Is it even possible to use it with MonoDevelop?

Moreover, what would be possible good alternatives to LINQ2SQL on Linux and OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbLinq is probably the closest to LINQ-to-SQL, and has [some support inside MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Linq); however, I expect it mainly means editing dbml (xml) files.

Comment: I can handle manual editing, the DB won't change much after the initial design. I did need a simpler ORM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate works on Mono as far as i know.